How to explain the relation between upper/lower limits of sequence of real numbers and sets?
Please be patient with my English as my first language is not English.
I'm currently learning set theory and I find myself puzzled about the relationship between the definitions of upper/lower limit of a sequence of real numbers {$x_k$} and sets {$A_k$}. Here are the definitions I'm working with: :
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup\limits_{k\geq n}x_k 
$$
$$
\varliminf\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\inf\limits_{k\geq n}x_k 
$$
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}A_k=\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup\limits_{k\geq n}A_k $$
$$
\varliminf\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}A_k=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap\limits_{k\geq n}A_k
$$
To illustrate, consider the sequence {$x_k$}$=${$\frac{1}{k}$}, if I view each $x_k$ as a single point set, i.e. $A_k=${$\frac{1}{k}$}, the limit of {$x_k$} is $0$, as are its upper and lower limits. However, $0$ does not belong to any single point set in {$A_k$}, and no element belongs to infinetly many sets in {$A_k$}. Consequently, the upper limit of {$A_k$} is empty set, thus the lower limit of {$A_k$} is also empty set. I also tried $A_k=(-\infty,x_k)$ but failed.
I am curious if there's a deeper connection between the two concepts of limit superior and limit inferior for sequences of real numbers and sets. Specifically, is there a way to construct intervals as sets that might clarify how the upper and lower limits of a sequence of real numbers are defined?
This is my first time posting here, so please forgive any inadvertent mistakes in how I've formatted my question.
Thank you for your help!

$1_{\lim \sup A_k}=\lim \sup 1_{A_K}$ etc. [$1_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise].

Thanks! I understand your point but I am still curious about how to use a sequence of intervals to explain $\varlimsup\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k$. I tried $A_k=(-\infty,x_k)$ but failed.
